# How to make windows 7 full screen on my secondary monitor

Tags: windows-7

[image]

I have a mid 2010 imac running mountain lion. I have just bought a Dell monitor secondhand. I am running Parallels Desktop 8 at the moment and have installed windows 7 on it.

When i drag Parallels Desktop to another monitor, it looks like as shown in the picture above.

How do i make it full screen?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried going in to the windows display settings and changing the resoultion to match the resoultion of the monitor? I don't know how parallels does it, some VM's only show one resolution and forces windows to resize itself and others let you set the resolution and the window for the VM resizes.

Comment: Also check if the physical monitor has the correct aspect ratio set

Comment: Thanks guys, I have adjusted the Display resolution and its now full screen, perfect. Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like the graphics drivers ain't installed correctly.
Find the manufactor of your graphics card and install newest version.

The most common are:

[ATI](http://www.amd.com/uk/Pages/AMDHomePage.aspx)
and
[Nvidia](http://www.nvidia.com/content/global/global.php)

The grahics drivers are not always installed by windows on a fresh install.

You will probably find graphics card updates in the Windows Update, but I would recommend using the manufactor directly to get the newest versions.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's the settings in the monitor, itself. I have an 16/10 Acer monitor that can be set up to automagically [Pillabox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pillarbox) itself if set to a 4/3 resolution. If your monitor has the same option, try disabling it. Or, set your XP resolution to something closer to 16/9 (preferably whatever your monitor's native resolution is).